# Depth buffers for different screens in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, buffer, depth

I don't quite understand how to handle **ZBuffering** for different screens in my program. I have a `screenControllers` class that calls a Draw method for each of my active `Screen` classes. The `spriteBatch.Begin` and `spriteBatch.End` calls are made in the `screenController`'s Draw. The `Screen`'s Draw just has a `spriteBatch.Draw` statement for each of the textures being drawn. I understand that I can specify depth when calling the

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Rectangle destinationRectangle,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth
)
```

method for `spriteBatch`.

But say I open one screen with textures at some given depth. Then, the second screen I open should have other textures at the same depth values as the previous but drawn in order on TOP of the previous screen. I doubt I will need this functionality because the second screen I open will probably be an options screen on top of my scene window with everything in front or it may be a portion of an interface that is not on top of the scene window but to the side. I am just wondering if this layered functionality for multiple screens can be implemented in XNA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use different `SpriteBatch` to manage them I don't think you will have this kind of problem.

If you use the same `SpriteBatch` you could use a `scaleFactor` and an `offsetValue` to manage the `layerDepth` value of your `Draw`s, in order to create different invervals for every sceen's `screenDepth` parameter.

I mean that if you have 2 screen the first's textures are drawn in the `[0, 0.5)` interval, the second one in `[0.5, 1)`. If you have 3 of them the interval will be every 0.33 and so on...

The `scaleFactor` will be `1 / numberOfScreens` of course.

Comment: What do you mean by different SpriteBatch to manage? Use different begin/end calls for each screen instead of a global one in screenController OR a different draw method? Also, for the first option, do you mean if I have 3 textures with depth (0.3,0.5,0.9) one one screen and two textures with (0.4,0.7) on the second screen and if I draw the second screen after the first one all the second screen textures will be on top of the first screen ones in the right order?

Comment: Both things are suitable for what I wrote, I think. Anyway I haven't tried something like that, but you understood what I meant. Is it true?

Comment: I didnt understand the bit about using the scaleFactor and offsetValue for the same spriteBatch. Why should the scale of the texture decrease with increasing number of screens? However, if you think using different sprite begin/end commands will layer it ocrrectly i'll give that a go. Sorry, I'm still new to xna...

Comment: What I mean is that you should scale the `layerDepth` value, not the texture, in order to create different intervals of `layerDepth` for each of your screenController. For example, in you have only two screenControllers, the screen that's behind should define each draw in the `[0, 0.5)` interval, and the screen that's in front should have the interval `[0.5, 1)` for the layerDepth. In this case the `scaleFactor` is 0.5 (because you have two screenController) and the `offset` is 0 for the first one and 0.5 for the second one.

Comment: You can manage this in every way you prefer, I'm just trying to give you the idea of how I'd implement this.

Comment: I've never touched depth buffers as an issue so this is still new to me. Do you know any good online resources covering this topic?